# JTable: RadioButton column: Select only one radio button

Tags: java, jtable

Java 1.8,

Here my radioButton render:

```
public class RadioButtonCellEditorRenderer extends AbstractCellEditor
        implements TableCellRenderer, TableCellEditor, ActionListener {

    private JRadioButton radioButton;

    public RadioButtonCellEditorRenderer() {
        this.radioButton = new JRadioButton();
        radioButton.addActionListener(this);
        radioButton.setOpaque(false);
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
            int row, int column) {
        radioButton.setSelected(Boolean.TRUE.equals(value));
        return radioButton;
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
        radioButton.setSelected(Boolean.TRUE.equals(value));
        return radioButton;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        stopCellEditing();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getCellEditorValue() {
        return radioButton.isSelected();
    }

}
```

And here how I use this class:

```
private void initTable() {
    TableColumn tableColumn = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < searchResultTable.getColumnCount(); i++) {
        tableColumn = searchResultTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(i);
        if (i == 0) {// check box
            tableColumn.setMaxWidth(40);
            tableColumn.setCellEditor(new RadioButtonCellEditorRenderer());
            tableColumn.setCellRenderer(new RadioButtonCellEditorRenderer());
        } 
    }
}
```

And here result:

[image]

As you can see I can select multiple radio buttons. But I need to select ONLY ONE radio buttons. How I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Add your radio buttons to a group

So I'm not exactly sure how your program works give this a shot

```
private void initTable() {
    TableColumn tableColumn = null;
    ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
    for (int i = 0; i < searchResultTable.getColumnCount(); i++) {
        tableColumn = searchResultTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(i);
        if (i == 0) {// check box
            tableColumn.setMaxWidth(40);
            RadioButtonCellEditorRenderer radioButtonCellEditorRenderer = new RadioButtonCellEditorRenderer();
            group.add(radioButtonCellEditorRenderer.getRadioButton());
            tableColumn.setCellEditor(radioButtonCellEditorRenderer);
            tableColumn.setCellRenderer(radioButtonCellEditorRenderer);
        }
    }
}
```

Also add this to your RadioButtonCellEditorRenderer class

```
public JRadioButton getRadioButton(){ return radioButton; }
```

Comment: Not help. Same result. I can't select only ONE radio button.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing with Radio button group here. See the below example. Try with this example and fix your issue. Hope this will help you.

```
 ButtonGroup bG = new ButtonGroup();

public RadioButtonCellEditorRenderer() {
    this.radioButton = new JRadioButton();
    radioButton.addActionListener(this);
    radioButton.setOpaque(false);
    bG.add(radioButton);//add this line
}
```

Comment: Not help. Same result. I can't select only ONE radio button